Coding a hamiltonian in qiskit
I have a hamiltonian of the form:
$H=\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i Z_{i+1}-Z_NZ_1$
And another one as:
$H=-\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$
I need it to it for N terms.
I am a bit lost can anybody help. I tried looking for tutorials but they use opflow which is deprecated now.

I am not sure whether I get your question. What do you mean by I need it to it for n terms. ?

N is a user input so it can be anything 1,2......

Qiskit's class SparsePauliOp can be used to define sparse $\text{N}$-qubit operators in Pauli basis representation. And in your case, it is better to utilize from_sparse_list method as follows:
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

# As an example, let N equals 5
N = 5

sparse_list = []
for m in range(N - 1):
    sparse_list.append(("ZZ", [m, m + 1], 1))

sparse_list.append(("ZZ", [N - 1, 0], -1))

hamiltonian1 = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list(sparse_list, num_qubits=N)
print(hamiltonian1)

Similarly, you can define the other hamiltonian
sparse_list = []
for m in range(N):
    sparse_list.append(("X", [m], -1))

hamiltonian2 = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list(sparse_list, num_qubits=N)
print(hamiltonian2)

Notes:

In Qiskit, qubits are indexed using a zero-based convention.
Qiskit uses little-endian ordering. So, when you print the hamiltonian $Z_0Z_1$ will be printed as IIIZZ

